# Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, Npgsql DDEX Provider Not showing "Functions"

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio-2015, npgsql, ddex

i use Npgsql DDEX Provider version 3.1 and Npgsql 3.1.8
my environtment is Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition,
i can connect to the Data Source PostgreSQL.
but i can only select table and views from the list.

the question is : the DDEX Provider not support functions ? i cannot select any functions or stored procedure

my functions return table. and have parameters

thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any chance you get this done?